# How to call same method n times using tasks to run in parallel in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I want to call method which does time consuming job from different threads.

```
Public void DoSomeWork(int n)
{
  // Time Consuming operation depending on n. 
}
```

1 - I am trying to use task instead of thread & threadpool.
2 - There should be at max n threads running in parallel
3 - While I tried to use 'SemaphoreSlim' I found it's calling same thread calling method multiple times and run into unhanded exception.

Implementation:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < SomeNumberList.Count; i++)
        {
            semaphore.Wait();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(SomeNumberList[i])).ContinueWith(x => semaphore.Release());
        }
```

How to use task to call DoSomeWork by concurrent threads using task and how to do error handling for it?

Comment: It's much easier than that. Take a look at Parallel.For

Comment: But how to control number of threads in Parallel.For ? I want to restrict number of threads.

Comment: See MaxDegreeOfParallelism inside ParallelOptions that you can pass in.

Comment: Thanks you! Can you write it in answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel.For already gives you the necessary marshalling for this sort of task.

```
    const int n = 5; // No more than "n threads"
    Parallel.For(0,  SomeNumberList.Count, new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = n}, i =>
    {
        DoSomeWork(i);
    }
```

There is another overload which gives you ParallelLoopState if you need to handle exceptions or break calls based on what is happening in concurrent executions.